# Greek letter in Maxima plot

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

How do you write greek letters as axeslabel with Maxima and/or wxMaxima?

In wxmaxima I tried by clicking on the greek letters in the left panel, but on the plot I got `theta` instead of $\theta$

Comment: Try entering the letter you want via copy/paste of Unicode characters, or, I guess, type it on the keyboard if you know how to enter Unicode characters (I don't). It might be necessary for the Lisp implementation to support Unicode; most do, the one which doesn't is GCL. What does `build_info();` report? Also, it might be possible to tell Gnuplot to display Greek letters by entering `\theta` or something like that; you'll have to check the Gnuplot documentation about that.